# How to Hide Dictionary Key in LookupEdit using C#?

Tags: c#, devexpress, repositorylookupedit

I created a normal winform and added `LookUpEdit` to my form and created a dictionary which contains `string` keys and `string` values.  I loaded my `LookupEdit.Properties.Datasource` using the `BindingSource`.
When Lookupedit is loaded, I want to hide dictionary Key:

```
private LookUpEdit lookup1;

void InitializeComponent()
{
    //...
    this.lookup1 = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.LookUpEdit();
    this.lookup1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
    //this.cmbCards.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    this.lookup1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(400, 125);
    this.lookup1.Name = "Test";
    this.lookup1.Properties.ShowHeader = false;
    this.lookup1.Properties.ValueMember = "Test";
    this.lookup1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 85);
    this.lookup1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.lookup1.Tag = "";
    this.lookup1.Properties.BestFit();
    this.lookup1.Properties.ShowDropDown = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ShowDropDown.SingleClick;
    this.lookup1.Properties.BestFit();
    this.lookup1.Properties.PopupWidth = 50;
    this.lookup1.Properties.PopupSizeable = false;
    //...
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dic.Add("Test", "1");
        dic.Add("Test2", "2");
        dic.Add("Test3", "3");
        dic.Add("Test4", "4");
        dic.Add("Test5", "5");
        dic.Add("Test6", "6");
        dic.Add("Test7", "7");
        dic.Add("Test8", "8");
        dic.Add("Test9", "9");
        dic.Add("Test10", "10");

        this.lookup1.Properties.DataSource = new BindingSource(dic, null);
        this.lookup1.Properties.ShowLines = false;
        this.lookup1.Properties.ShowPopupShadow = false;
        this.lookup1.ItemIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

This shows the following:

```
Output 
Test  1
Test2 2
```

I need Output as  '1'
'Test' has to be hide.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**
Just add two columns to `lookupEdit` and then assign `datasource`. after that you will be able to access these columns. Dynamically generated columns does not added to `lookupEdit.properties.Columns` collection.

Refer [LookUpEdit Class](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic)

Use this:

```
private void CreateLookupEdit()
{
    ledMyControl = new LookUpEdit();
    ledMyControl.Properties.Columns.Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("Key"));
    ledMyControl.Properties.Columns.Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("Value"));

    this.Controls.Add(ledMyControl);
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dic.Add("Test", "1");
    dic.Add("Test2", "2");
    dic.Add("Test3", "3");
    dic.Add("Test4", "4");
    dic.Add("Test5", "5");
    dic.Add("Test6", "6");
    dic.Add("Test7", "7");
    dic.Add("Test8", "8");
    dic.Add("Test9", "9");
    dic.Add("Test10", "10");
    ledMyControl.Properties.DisplayMember = "Value";
    ledMyControl.Properties.ValueMember = "Key";
    ledMyControl.Properties.DataSource = dic.ToList();

    ledMyControl.Properties.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
```

References:
[Dictionary as datasource](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q131292.aspx)
[LookupEdit bound to ArrayList](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q246473.aspx)
[Feed lookupEdit with Dictionary](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q441481.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Manage  the following event in code behind

```
lookup1.Popup += new EventHandler(gridLookUpEdit1_Popup);

protected void gridLookUpEdit1_Popup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.lookup1.Properties.View.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: In LookUpEdit there is nothing property like that as what u mentioned ... but u can do like this                             this.lookup1.Properties.Columns[0].Visible = false; ,... this also fails

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index it sayh this error